# Can the jquery flot graph project handle discontinuous points

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a requirement for a multiple series line graph.

I am looking at pure javascript solutions and feel flot looks like a good option.

However the points along the line may not be continuous but I want the line to be joined.

ie

y        [Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun]

Series 1 [4    4       5   6   7]
Series 2 [5    6   7   8   9   9]

Although there is no value for Series 1 March I want flot to draw a smooth line between Feb and Apr.

I would very much appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with Flot, it *will* draw a smooth line between Feb and Apr, you don't need to do anything special for that.  However, if there is no data for, say, January and February, then it will make a line that starts with March, which does look a little odd, but there's not really a good alternative (flot or otherwise) unless you extrapolate (which is riskier than interpolating).